# How to hide div while the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div whose display is "none" in css: `display:none;`. And it is supposed to stay hidden even after the page loads but while the page is loading it is being displayed like a flash, for a second, and hiding again.

Is there any way, with JQuery, that I can override it to stay hidden during the entire operation?

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7" >
      <div id="documentStatus_div">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `css` file included in `<head>` ?

Comment: can you please add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: If you're css file is quite large it's possible it's taking too long to load the file before the styles are applied, you could add `style="display:none"` on the div it self, that way it will definitely render as hidden to start with.

Comment: @Shannon yes css is large and have already added display:none

Comment: We need more information then, if you've added display:none inline on the div itself then I would say something else is flashing not the div in question.

Answer (score 0):

This code defiantly work for you...

**CSS Code :**

```
<style>
    .display_none {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="dispnone" class="display_none">123</div>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
$("#dispnone").removeClass("display_none");

setTimeout(
     "$('#dispnone').addClass('display_none');",
2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure to add your css link between `<head>` tag.

Please clear cache and test again. If your css file is too large, you can set inline style for hidden this div.

If you want to hide with jquery, you can disable like this `$("#documentStatus_div").prop("disabled")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the style as display:none for both the divs :-

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7" style="display:none">
      <div id="documentStatus_div" style="display:none>...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for some like this? Cause this is what I understand. If not, pls tell me.

```js
function showDiv(){
 $('.div-flash').slideToggle(300)
  $('.div-flash').delay(500).slideToggle(500);
};

showDiv();
```

```css
body{
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.div-flash{
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  This is all doc
</div>

<div class="div-flash">
  This will show and hide
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for this is your CSS file is taking time to load.

**Method 1:** Use an inline style

```
<div id="documentStatus_div" style="display:none>...</div>
```

**Method 2:** Check CSS link is present in `<head>` section

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7" style="display:none;">
      <div id="documentStatus_div">...</div>
</div>
```